# Maven can't build a project with multiple source directories

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors

I'm converting in maven an old project that originally rely on eclipse and ant to build.
Stated that I can't chancge the directory layout of that project, I would like to produce some artifact similar to ones build with that ant script. The original project, build all classes with from subprojects in one directory with eclipse, then package the resulting classes with ant in subpackages (different from subprojects).

To deal with this requirements I've done the following structure: (as now only one of the subpackage)

```
warp-parent
|
|- pom.xml
|- warp-client
|  |
|  | - pom.xml
```

the parent pom is the following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>it.sinesy.warp</groupId>
<artifactId>warp-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>warp-parent</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                         <sources>
                             <source>../../src</source>
                             <source>../../srcj2ee</source>
                             <source>../../srcjsf</source>
                             <source>../../srcrest</source>
                             <source>../../srcswing</source>
                             <source>../../srctest</source>
                             <source>../../srcweb</source>
                             <source>../../srcws</source>
                         </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
</dependencies>

<modules>
    <module>warp-client</module>
</modules>
</project>
```

and the child one:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>it.sinesy.warp</groupId>
    <artifactId>warp-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<groupId>it.sinesy.warp</groupId>
<artifactId>warp-client</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>warp-client</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
         <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.1</version>
             <configuration>
                 <includes>
                     <include>**</include>
                     <!--
                     <include>**/it/tinet/warp/swing/**/java/*</include>
                     <include>**/it/tinet/warp/common/**/java/*</include>
                     <include>**/it/tinet/warp/swing/**/client/*</include> -->
                 </includes>
             </configuration>
         </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

When I try to compile to compile the parent pom I got the following output, with no source compiled:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] warp-parent
[INFO] warp-client
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building warp-parent 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:add-source (add-source) @ warp-parent ---
[INFO] Source directory: /home/elettronik/test/warp/warp_src/src added.
[INFO] Source directory: /home/elettronik/test/warp/warp_src/srcj2ee added.
[INFO] Source directory: /home/elettronik/test/warp/warp_src/srcjsf added.
[INFO] Source directory: /home/elettronik/test/warp/warp_src/srcrest added.
[INFO] Source directory: /home/elettronik/test/warp/warp_src/srcswing added.
[INFO] Source directory: /home/elettronik/test/warp/warp_src/srctest added.
[INFO] Source directory: /home/elettronik/test/warp/warp_src/srcweb added.
[INFO] Source directory: /home/elettronik/test/warp/warp_src/srcws added.
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building warp-client 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:add-source (add-source) @ warp-client ---
[INFO] Source directory: /home/elettronik/test/warp/warp_src/mvn/src added.
[INFO] Source directory: /home/elettronik/test/warp/warp_src/mvn/srcj2ee added.
[INFO] Source directory: /home/elettronik/test/warp/warp_src/mvn/srcjsf added.
[INFO] Source directory: /home/elettronik/test/warp/warp_src/mvn/srcrest added.
[INFO] Source directory: /home/elettronik/test/warp/warp_src/mvn/srcswing added.
[INFO] Source directory: /home/elettronik/test/warp/warp_src/mvn/srctest added.
[INFO] Source directory: /home/elettronik/test/warp/warp_src/mvn/srcweb added.
[INFO] Source directory: /home/elettronik/test/warp/warp_src/mvn/srcws added.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ warp-client ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/elettronik/test/warp/warp_src/mvn/warp-parent/warp-client/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ warp-client ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] warp-parent ....................................... SUCCESS [0.762s]
[INFO] warp-client ....................................... SUCCESS [1.389s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.389s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Aug 16 14:03:32 CEST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/109M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Could someone give some advice to make this work? thanks to all.

Comment: Can't you just compile those sources as a separate module under warp-parent and add it as dependency to warp-client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent-pom shows `<packaging>pom</packaging>` so the sources you define in the parent pom will not be compiled.

Comment: the log: `(default-compile) @ warp-client` means its referring to the module project's sources.

Comment: So the best solution is define path as property in prent pom and add that path as source for children poms?

Comment: Yes indeed , just make sure you use the buildhelper plugin with the corresponding sources in every child project you are compiling.